# Array operation; Fortran equivalent of (:)

Tags: c++, c++14

I am converting from Fortran to C++ . In Fortran on a 2D array ie `A(1000,3)` i can do the following:

```
A(1,:)=(x0,y0,z0)
```

I have searched online and haven't found anything close to that for C++ so I can vectorize some operations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, can you briefly explain `A(1,:)=(x0,y0,z0)` please? I'm not familiar with Fortran.

Comment: Are arrays or is `A` array in fortran dynamically allocated or statically?

Comment: Let's say A is a statically allocated array then A(1,:)=0 means setting all columns of the first row to zero.

Comment: You may either use custom class representing an array of use `std::valarray`.

Comment: @JeJo What?  I apologise.

Comment: Just iterate over elements and set each of them.

Comment: @KamilCuk I consider that to be bad practice for heavy computations

Comment: @JeJo Ok i got it.  Thanks anyways

Comment: How? Why? How do you want to set each element of an array to a value if not iterating over them? Then how do you think fortran does the operation?

Comment: @KamilCuk Well I just try to avoid as much as possible for loops in my code. I also think computationally the method I described is faster than a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ language does not include a built-in matrix type, but includes all the tools you need to build one. Fortunately, that does **not** mean you need to go and build one all by yourself. Indeed, that would be a bit like reinventing the wheel.

I suggest you rely on one of the existing C++ open source matrix/vector packages, rather than defining ad hoc types manually. One possibility consists of using the Armadillo library.

[Armadillo Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo_(C%2B%2B_library))

[Armadillo online documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

What you want to do can be done like this:
A.row(0) = rowvec{x0, y0, z0};

Example of self-contained source code below:

```
#include  <armadillo>
#include  <iostream>

using  arma::Mat;
using  arma::vec;
using  arma::rowvec;
using  arma::colvec;


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Mat<double>     A = Mat<double>(1000, 3, arma::fill::zeros);

    std::cout << "Shape of matrix A: " <<
                 A.n_rows << "x" << A.n_cols << std::endl;

    double  x0 = 1.5;
    double  y0 = 2.5;
    double  z0 = 3.5;

    A.row(0) = rowvec{x0, y0, z0};  // HERE

    std::cout << "  A(0,0)=" << A(0,0) << "  A(0,1)=" << A(0,1) 
              << "  A(0,2)=" << A(0,2)  << std::endl;

    std::cout << "  A(1,0)=" << A(1,0) << "  A(1,1)=" << A(1,1)
              << "  A(1,2)=" << A(1,2)  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The specialized libraries go much further than this. For example, you can write a matrix product just like P=A*B, and the library will gracefully call the appropriate highly optimized BLAS/LAPACK backend routines for you. You can remain blissfully ignorant of the sad facts that the backend is Fortran-based and thus insists on numbering array elements from 1 not 0, and also insists on storing 2-dimensional arrays in contiguous columns, unlike C/C++ which prefers contiguous rows.

Of course it will take some time to learn about one the existing libraries, but it is unfortunately possible that writing/debugging your own type system will take even more time.

Alternatively, if you insist on designing/using your own C++ linear algebra package, you could do worse than getting a copy of this book:
 "The C++ Programming Language, 4th edition"
by Bjarne Stroustrup, ISBN 978-0321-563842.

As you probably know, the C++ initial design effort, and a good chunk of the subsequent language evolution was led by this author. The 4th edition of his book includes a chapter 29 (taking only 30  pages) whose title is: "**A matrix design**". Chapter 29 makes extensive use of "advanced" features of C++11 such as template types and operator overloading.

**Regarding elementary C++ types:**

Using an array of std::arrays assume that you know the size of your matrix at compile time. This is a restriction that was fortunately removed from modern versions of Fortran.

Using a vector of vector would allocate the memory space of the matrix as N separate areas, and that would be both less time-efficient and incompatible with BLAS/LAPACK backend libraries.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the extensive reply. It's a valuable help to me! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If using `std::array` containers and using `std::array::operator=` you could do this:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 1000> A;
int x0, y0, z0;
A[0] = std::array<int, 3>{x0, y0, z0};
```